# Selecting range limits of a scale in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to apply a fee to an amount according with this scale:

```
AMOUNT     FEE
-------     ---
0           24.04 €
6010.12     0.00450
30050.61    0.00150
60101.21    0.00100
150253.03   0.00050
601012.11   0.00030
```

From 0 to 6010.13€ is a fix fee of 24.04€

My code:

```
def fee(amount):
    scale = [[0, 24.04],
             [6010.12, 0.00450],
             [30050.61, 0.00150],
             [60101.21, 0.00100],
             [150253.03, 0.00050],
             [601012.11, 0.00030]]
    if amount <= scale[1][0]:
        fee = scale[0][1]
    else:
        for i in range(0, 5):
            if amount >= scale[i][0] and amount < scale[i+1][0]:
                fee = amount * scale[i][1]
                break
    return fee

print(fee(601012.12))
```

This code works fine from 0€ to 601012.11€, but for 601012.12€ or greater fails.

> ```
> return fee UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fee' referenced before assignment
> ```

I suppose that the problem is here: `amount < scale[i+1][0]` when i=4 the `fee` variable isn't assigned.

Are there any methods more pythonic to select range limits of a scale?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing two different semantics for the scale list. In the code, you treat the list as a sequence of intervals. This would  mean, that values below `0` and above `601012.11`. are not defined. But from your description, it looks like you want the highest entry from the list where the input value is still above the first element of the entry pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better way would be to use a while loop to check if `amount` is lesser then `scale[i+1][0]` so that you may just use `scale[i][1]`. And also give an else to handle anything greater than `scale[len(scale)][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't handling that one case. You should just add another `if` statement outside the loop (similar to the `if ammount <= scale[1][0]` you used, because values in both of these ranges are not handled by the loop):

```
if ammount >= scale[len(scale) - 1][0]:
    fee = scale[len(scale) - 1][1]
```

<sup>Btw, there's a little inconsistency with the `<=` for the first `if`, but `>=` and `<` for the second, in the loop.</sup>

I doubt I can make better than this:

```
for i in range(-1, len(scale) - 1):
    if((i == -1 or ammount >= scale[i][0]) and
       (i == len(scale) or ammount < scale[i + 1][0])):
        fee = ammount * scale[i][1]
        return fee
```

`scale[-1][0]` and `scale[len(scale)][0]` cannot be executed, so they're short-circuited.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try to avoid naming different things the same. That makes harder to see what the problem is.

What happens is this: if the amount is below the second entry in the scale table, you return the first entry. If not, you look in the table and check if the amount is bigger than the current and smaller than the next threshold. That works up until the last one, your `range(0, 5)` will yield `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`, not reaching the last one and breaking.
In that case, no `fee` is defined when you try to return it, raising the UnboundLocalError. I would fix by checking the upper bound too:

```
def fee(amount):
    scale = [[0, 24.04],
             [6010.12, 0.00450],
             [30050.61, 0.00150],
             [60101.21, 0.00100],
             [150253.03, 0.00050],
             [601012.11, 0.00030]]
    if amount <= scale[1][0]:
        return scale[0][1]
    elif amount >= scale[-1][0]:
        return scale[-1][1]
    else:
        for i in range(0, 5):
            if amount >= scale[i][0] and amount < scale[i + 1][0]:
                return amount * scale[i][1]
```

Comment: But indeed, as mentioned by @logicStuff, this is not very pythonic.